# Validating a date for SQL Server in Yii

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, yii

I have a model with a creation_date field which is being assigned the current date when empty and will not be modified afterwards. I also want to validate the date as to prevent incorrect queries, so here are the rules for this field:

```
<?php
        array('creation_date', 'default', 'value' => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')),
        array('[...bunch of fields...], creation_date', 'required'),
        array('creation_date', 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss'),
?>
```

Everything is fine if I insert a new record, but if I update a row (without modifying the creation_date) I get a validation error because the date fetched from SQL Server will include milliseconds (e.g. `2012-11-29 11:24:26.000`). I would add the milliseconds to the validation format, but it is not possible[1].

Is there a way to fix this without hacks? Or should I just drop the format validation?

[1] http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateTimeParser

Comment: Doesn't PHP have a function that will allow you to format the date before you validate it? You can do this in SQL Server too but it seems PHP is the better place to do it.

Comment: PHP has a function to format the date, but what is the point of having ActiveRecord and re-assigning the value to format it the right way? This is the hack I was talking about and would like to avoid it as much as possible...

Comment: Then run your "hack" in SQL Server instead using the `CONVERT` function. `CONVERT(CHAR(10), creation_date, 120) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), creation_date, 108);` - you tell me, is that a more or less elegant hack?

Comment: I would rather drop the format validation, it is not a user-assigned field in any way, but it would make my model more robust. I could also use substr() to eliminate the trailing characters, but still a hack...